# Handle Windows Open File dialog in Selenium

Tags: selenium

How can handle Window Open File dialog (set file path and import) using javascript (or some other way) in Selenium ?

Comment: Are you trying to upload a file on a web page? In other words, is there an `<input type=‘file’>` element on the page somewhere?

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to upload a file, and the page in question uses the standard upload mechanisms provided by HTML, you can do this directly with Selenium itself. The standard HTML mechanism is with an `<input type=‘file’>` element. Once you’ve found that file upload element on the page, you can use `element.sendKeys(“full/path/and/file/name/here”);`. This is documented in Step 10 of the algorithm for the [Element Send Keys command of the W3C WebDriver Specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-element-send-keys), and is used in several file upload tests in the Selenium project’s test code ([example](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/UploadTest.java)).

Answer (score 0):

//set file path
driver.findelelment(By.Xpath("//input[contains(@type,'file')]")).SendKeys(UploadFilePath);